# How to use pivot function on 2 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, pivot-table

I am trying to understand how to use the PIVOT function of SQL Server to pivot 2 columns. Most of the examples I have seen, use more than 2 columns, and I am not sure how to apply when using less columns.

Any help would be kindly appreciated.

The columns are shopper_id, and sku, I need to have the shopper_id in one column and the sku to the left separated by commas.

Here is my query that needs to be pivoted:

```
    SELECT
      [a].[shopper_id]
    , [a].[sku]
    FROM
     ( SELECT
         [s].[shopper_id]
       , [si].[sku]
       FROM
         [dbo].[sales] [s]
       INNER JOIN [dbo].[sales_item] [si]
       ON
         [si].[order_id] = [s].[order_id]
       WHERE
         [si].[sku] IS NOT NULL
         AND [si].[sku] NOT LIKE ''
       ORDER BY
         [si].[sku]
     ) [a];
```

And here is some of the data:

```
0ZF57CFXCBTF4G2X68B9DKH1C9DNUN37    BKAL00-30013
72YHJYU0QFMSNC61RG42TGTD53FDUM37    BKAL00-30013
4U3H3V4LX193NLY4C0FXJJD2SSS3BT37    BKAL00-30013
7UQBXPWB0CSXNYYNB1R360BJHKCQ6F47    BKAL00-30013
6WTCMTS6551PNGQRKDZRZ6NLRMB011P6    BKAL00-30013
784HKB96M5SN4VBU18U0Y3WH037F2147    BKAL0011674X
784HKB96M5SN4VBU18U0Y3WH037F2147    BKAL0011675X
TDK8YDJQMTHL48GNGVXGS6RBUCHPKK37    BKAL0020413X
R472477HL8C8N2GBP9TG6F1K7N5JV1P6    BKAL0024498
ZSM7F5FNYBXDNZU3KZTV71PY58K8KQ17    BKAL0024498
YPF1NDD5Z35V4GGMXXPCWRUF56NTKYB6    BKAL0024498
CGNYSNFF0M0WNLU2FW6NRKJ7JQL6MBW5    BKAL0025397
Y7J85S5M29LG45Y69H2QDJFX5JB17D47    BKAL0025397
```

The expected output should be:

```
shopper id                          sku1      sku2      sku3     so on...
00000148-4CDD-46C1-BD86-DF001A      MN0042258 MN0073222 MN0044842
so on...
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: and the expected output would be?

Comment: I added the expected output example

Comment: Now you don't want a comma separated list but made up column names?

Comment: Added another answer using dynamic pivot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You stated you wanted a comma seperated list. You would do that like so:

```
declare @table table (shopper_id nvarchar(256), sku nvarchar(256))
insert into @table
values
('0ZF57CFXCBTF4G2X68B9DKH1C9DNUN37','BKAL00-30013'),
('72YHJYU0QFMSNC61RG42TGTD53FDUM37','BKAL00-30013'),
('4U3H3V4LX193NLY4C0FXJJD2SSS3BT37','BKAL00-30013'),
('7UQBXPWB0CSXNYYNB1R360BJHKCQ6F47','BKAL00-30013'),
('6WTCMTS6551PNGQRKDZRZ6NLRMB011P6','BKAL00-30013'),
('784HKB96M5SN4VBU18U0Y3WH037F2147','BKAL0011674X'),
('784HKB96M5SN4VBU18U0Y3WH037F2147','BKAL0011675X'),
('TDK8YDJQMTHL48GNGVXGS6RBUCHPKK37','BKAL0020413X'),
('R472477HL8C8N2GBP9TG6F1K7N5JV1P6','BKAL0024498'),
('ZSM7F5FNYBXDNZU3KZTV71PY58K8KQ17','BKAL0024498'),
('YPF1NDD5Z35V4GGMXXPCWRUF56NTKYB6','BKAL0024498'),
('CGNYSNFF0M0WNLU2FW6NRKJ7JQL6MBW5','BKAL0025397'),
('Y7J85S5M29LG45Y69H2QDJFX5JB17D47','BKAL0025397')

select distinct
    shopper_id,
    skuList = STUFF((
                      SELECT ',' + md.sku
                      FROM @table md
                      WHERE m.shopper_id = md.shopper_id
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
from
    @table m
```

**EDIT Based on your last edit**

```
if object_id('tempdb..#Table') is not null drop table #Table

create table #Table (shopper_id nvarchar(256), sku nvarchar(256))
insert into #Table
values
('0ZF57CFXCBTF4G2X68B9DKH1C9DNUN37','BKAL00-30013'),
('72YHJYU0QFMSNC61RG42TGTD53FDUM37','BKAL00-30013'),
('4U3H3V4LX193NLY4C0FXJJD2SSS3BT37','BKAL00-30013'),
('7UQBXPWB0CSXNYYNB1R360BJHKCQ6F47','BKAL00-30013'),
('6WTCMTS6551PNGQRKDZRZ6NLRMB011P6','BKAL00-30013'),
('784HKB96M5SN4VBU18U0Y3WH037F2147','BKAL0011674X'),
('784HKB96M5SN4VBU18U0Y3WH037F2147','BKAL0011675X'),
('TDK8YDJQMTHL48GNGVXGS6RBUCHPKK37','BKAL0020413X'),
('R472477HL8C8N2GBP9TG6F1K7N5JV1P6','BKAL0024498'),
('ZSM7F5FNYBXDNZU3KZTV71PY58K8KQ17','BKAL0024498'),
('YPF1NDD5Z35V4GGMXXPCWRUF56NTKYB6','BKAL0024498'),
('CGNYSNFF0M0WNLU2FW6NRKJ7JQL6MBW5','BKAL0025397'),
('Y7J85S5M29LG45Y69H2QDJFX5JB17D47','BKAL0025397')


if object_id('tempdb..#StagingTable') is not null drop table #StagingTable
select 
    * 
    ,'sku'+ cast(row_number() over (partition by shopper_id order by (select null)) as varchar(64)) as RN
into #StagingTable
from #Table


DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column 
SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') 
       + QUOTENAME(RN)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT RN FROM #StagingTable) AS Cname

--Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic 
SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
  N'SELECT shopper_id, ' + @ColumnName + '
    FROM #StagingTable
    PIVOT(min(sku) 
          FOR RN IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'
--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

Comment: Thank you, I am trying to use my select query for the insert of values in the temp table, when I do this, I get an error message: The number of elements in the select list exceeds the maximum allowed number of 4096 elements. - Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Nope. No idea why. You should be able to do something like`SELECT
      [a].[shopper_id]
    , [a].[sku]
    into #Table
    FROM
     ( SELECT
         [s].[shopper_id]
       , [si].[sku]
       FROM
         [dbo].[sales] [s]
       INNER JOIN [dbo].[sales_item] [si]
       ON
         [si].[order_id] = [s].[order_id]
       WHERE
         [si].[sku] IS NOT NULL
         AND [si].[sku] NOT LIKE ''
       ORDER BY
         [si].[sku]
     ) [a]` but that would be another question to ask on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am trying to do, but not working

Comment: Well your outer select is pointless. Just use the inner query in parentheses